# Skipping loop iterations based on type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an array of both objects (JSX elements) and strings, which I want to iterate over and perform logic on the items that are strings, but skip the objects.

```
const array= ['string', {...}, {...}, 'string', 'string', {...}];
 for (let i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) { if( {/* This is an object */} ){continue;}else{
{/* perform logic */}}
```

Is is possible to continue a loop based on type?

Answer (score 1):

The [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator should do what you want. However, if the logic you wish to perform only works on strings then you may want to consider inverting your logic to guard against the potential for your array to contain additional data types in the future.

Something like:

```
const array= ['string', {...}, {...}, 'string', 'string', {...}];
    
for (let i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {
  const str = array[i]  
  if( typeof str === 'string'){
        /* perform logic on str */
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work, however Typescript is still unhappy when trying to perform string based methods such as .replace() throwing me the error "Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'string | object'.
  Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'object'."

Comment: Just updated for TS - I think this should allow you to use String methods without ts screaming at you.

Comment: Thanks! If this answer worked for you and you don't mind accepting, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

See the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator.

eg.

```js
if (typeof array[i] !== 'string') {
  continue;
}
```